# Experiment : Test class will still read deleted field although it has been deleted?

Tags: custom-field

This is new finding for me and I really want to know if this happen to you or only me.

There is a custom field with text area created with more than 255 character. It created successfully although the default value is more than 255 characters. 
The funny thing is, when we try to insert the record it will prompt

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: STRING_TOO_LONG, Declaration: data value too large

First question : Why it allow us to create Default value more than 255 while it has limitation 255 character?

I run the test class and of course it hit the error because of the default value in custom field.Please note,the custom field is not called from the apex class , it inserted automatically when we insert the record because it is using default value.

So I delete the custom field and run the test again. It still give me the same error.So what I do is I erase that custom field , and rerun the test. The test class run successfully.

This lead to another question: if deleted field will still readable although it is not being called and deleted ?

I don't have developer licence so I m not able to ask Salesforce support, but I want to know if have you face the situation above.

The issue solved by erasing the field but I just wondering if there any supporting fact on my case today?